# How to have 2x1 subcaption structure?

Tags: graphics, subcaption

I want to have two figures (a-b) at the left-hand-side and the big image (c) at the right-hand-side alone with `subcaption` package, not `subfigure`. 
Code which output in Fig. 1

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption} % subfigure

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
      \centering
        \subcaptionbox{1}[0.65\textwidth]{\centering \includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{example-image}}
          \hfill
        \subcaptionbox{2}[0.3\textwidth]{\centering \includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \subcaptionbox{3}[0.65\textwidth]{\centering \includegraphics{example-image}}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Fig. 1 Output

[image]

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.7

Comment: sorry, was too fast. Retracted the vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Measure the big image first.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption} % subfigure

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\sbox{\tempbox}{% The big image
  \includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{example-image}%
}

\parbox[b][\ht\tempbox][s]{0.2\textwidth}{%
  \subcaptionbox{1}{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}}
  \vfill
  \subcaptionbox{2}{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}}
}\qquad
\subcaptionbox{3}{\usebox{\tempbox}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With `\parbox[b][\ht\tempbox][s]{...}` we say LaTeX: I'd like to get a box as high as `\tempbox` (with `[\ht\tempbox]`), using the inside vertical spacing to reach the goal height (with `[s]`), but whose apparent vertical alignment is at the “bottom item”.

Actually we use the fact that `\subcaptionbox` places the reference point at the material in the argument and the caption is below the reference point (as depth of the box).

[image]

Comment: Why do you need `\newsavebox{\tempbox}`?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Otherwise I couldn't use `\sbox{\tempbox}`.

Comment: I confirm, this proposal works!

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption} % subfigure

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Caption for A}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Caption for B}
        \end{subfigure}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfil
        \begin{minipage}{0.65\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{Caption for C}
        \end{subfigure}
        \end{minipage}
    \caption{The whole figure..}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 the `subcaption` package defines a `subfigure` environment as well. @ egreg's answer should do you fine then :)